# Stackapplet redirect me to "Page Not Found" page?

Tags: 12.04, stackapplet

When I click on one of my accounts in StackApplet on Ubuntu 12.04, it redirects me to a page that says "Page Not Found". The redirected page is `http://askubuntu.com/users/recent/78740` but I guess it should redirect me to `http://askubuntu.com/users/78740/saeed-zarinfam`.
I use stackapplet-1.4.0-2.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Finally i can install version 1.5.1 but generally stackapplet is not a good applet, it only shows my reputation and nothing else.

Comment: There is a beta version of StackApplet 1.6 available which displays the contents of your Stack Exchange inbox. It does have a few problems with the AppIndicator framework though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ubuntu 13.10+

Saucy ships with StackApplet 1.5.1, so the bug described below does not apply to you.

### Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, & 13.04

This was [a known bug filed on Launchpad last year](https://launchpad.net/r) that was fixed with version 1.5 of StackApplet. Unfortunately the current version of StackApplet shipping in the archives is 1.4, which was released nearly two years ago.

You can grab the latest stable version (1.5.1) by adding my PPA:

[ppa:george-edison55/george-edison [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/george-edison) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

You can then install StackApplet with:

```
sudo apt-get install stackapplet
```